# Lucene and Classic ASP?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, asp-classic, full-text-search

I have a legacy app in which I need to enable search.

I was looking at either Lucene or FTS of SQL Server.

However my question is...would Lucene work with Classic ASP? Any links?

Thanks!

Vladan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no Lucene for VBScript ([source](http://wiki.apache.org/lucene-java/LuceneImplementations)), but can use the [.Net implementation](http://incubator.apache.org/lucene.net/) and access the searched records via a standard webservice or an AJAX call returning JSON.

Comment: Yep, had that idea myself...still..was hoping ;)